# create new column in a dataframe using custom aggregate function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

Suppose I have a pandas data frame like:

```
         Date  Type  Rate  Load
0  2017-01-02  Rain    23    10
1  2017-01-02   Dry    30    15
2  2017-01-02  Rain    32    20
....
```

I also have a cost function
`cost(Type, Rate)` returning some real number.

How can I create a new column that for each row calculates the sum of `Load` all other rows having the same `Date` and having less `cost()` of that given row.

For example, if the cost function is simply:

```
def cost(Type, Rate):
    if Type=='Rain':
        return Rate/12
    else:
        return Rate/17
```

The output will be:

```
         Date  Type  Rate  Load  Output
0  2017-01-02  Rain    23    10   15           
1  2017-01-02   Dry    30    15   0          
2  2017-01-02  Rain    32    20   15+10=25    
....
```

Update. The current way that I'm thinking about is to create a new column that calculates the `cost` of each row first, and at the next step, create a new column that sums up the all the records for each row that has the same date, and having the lesser cost. But is there any faster way to combine both of these?

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: @Datanovice No, I meant I have a custom function for cost.

Comment: for your example none of the Load are less than cost? you have `1.9, 1.7,2.6`

Comment: Your example is not clear at all. How did you come to 15 in row 0? the sum of load is 45-1.91 (thats 23/12) from your cost function. please provide a clear example.

Comment: @Datanovice So if you consider `1.9, 1.7, 2.6`:
for first (row i.e., 1.9) the only row that has the lesser cost is the second row, so the output will be only 15.
for the second row: no records has lesser cost than 1.7, so the output will be 0.
and for the third row, the cost is higher than all other records, so the output will be sum of all other, i.e., 15+10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this with `df.to_records()`:

```
print(df)
cost= lambda Type, Rate:  Rate/12 if Type=='Rain' else Rate/17

l=[sum([j[4] for j in df.to_records() if list(j)[1]==list(i)[1] and list(i)!=list(j) and cost(list(j)[2],list(j)[3])<cost(list(i)[2],list(i)[3])]) for i in df.to_records()]
df['Output']=l
print(df)
```

Output:

```
df:
        Date  Type  Rate  Load
0 2017-01-01  Rain    23    10
1 2017-01-01   Dry    22    10
2 2017-01-01  Rain    25    10
3 2017-01-02   Dry    30    15
4 2017-01-02  Rain    32    20

df with output column:
        Date  Type  Rate  Load  Output
0 2017-01-01  Rain    23    10      10
1 2017-01-01   Dry    22    10       0
2 2017-01-01  Rain    25    10      20
3 2017-01-02   Dry    30    15       0
4 2017-01-02  Rain    32    20      15
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
row_sum = df.groupby(["Date"]).sum()
costs = [row_sum[row_sum["Date"] == i["Date"]] - cost(i["Type"], i["Rate"]) for i in df.iterrows()])

df["Output"] = costs
```

Comment: Sorry I think my example wasn't clear, I revised it.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.